# JestJS test not failing on error

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, typescript, jestjs

I am writing a typescript library and testing it using Jest. Here is my code:

```
export function populateTasks(inputFilePath: string): Task[] {
    if (!inputFilePath) {
        throw new Error("Input file path is null: " + inputFilePath);
    }
    const tasks: Task[] = [];
    readFile(inputFilePath, (err, data) => handleInputFile(err, data));
    return tasks;
}

function handleInputFile(err: any, data: any): void {
    if (err) {
        console.log("File not found");
        throw new Error("File not found: " + err);
    }
    console.log(data.toString());
}
```

And here is my test:

```
describe("test", () => {
    test("just a test", () => {
        populateTasks("tasks"); // Invalid file path
    });
});
```

Since the path is invalid *handleInputFile* should throw an error and test should fail. However, currently its printing *file not found* to the console but the test passes.
How do I get the test to fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it should be the other way around: if the function is expected to throw (given an invalid path), then the test should pass.

Use [.toThrow(error)](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/expect.html#tothrowerror):

```
test("should throw if path is invalid", () => {
    expect(() => populateTasks("tasks")).toThrow();
});

test("should not throw if path is valid", () => {
    expect(() => populateTasks("../tasks")).not.toThrow();
});
```

Comment: But the test should fail if I don't expect the function to throw an exception and it actually does. However in my case, it passes even when I am throwing an exception explicitly.

Comment: It seems the problem was with using async function for file. Fixed it by using *readFileSync*.